# Sync contacts to Outlook People

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sync, microsoft-account, outlook, people

Why can't i find half of my contacts in [Outlook People](https://office.live.com/start/People.aspx)? How can i sync my entire contacts into Outlook People? Checked it since i was about to reset my phone.

More Info:
I checked my phone, there's two accounts that the contacts are saved into, Microsoft Account and Outlook (Mail and Calendar). The ones that are shown in Outlook People(Web) are the Outlook (Mail and Calendar) contacts while the Microsoft Account contacts are missing.

I tried syncing, adding new contacts to each accounts in which the new outlook contacts are shown but missing the other.

My phone is a Microsoft 540 with Windows 10.
Version 1607

OS build: 10.0.14393.2007

Comment: What phone do you use? What version of Windows Phone or Windows 10 Mobile is it running? The People app aggregates contacts from multiple services, are you sure the ones that are missing from Outlook aren't from Twitter, Facebook or other external service?

Comment: Its the Microsoft account contacts that are missing and the Outlook account contacts that are shown

Comment: If i reset the phone, is there any chance that i lose these microsoft account contacts?